# My Cordova app does not connect to internet anymore when in wifi

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have upgraded to cordova 5.2.0 and I'm also using crosswalk v14+ with the [plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview).
I'm running my app on my Android phone and on my Android tablet and before the upgrade everything was working (I had to upgrade because I had some issues that have been resolved in new versions) now my app can connect to internet only in 2g/3g, when in wifi the connection does not work.

I tried to install `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and to check that I have all permissions in my `config.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml`:

in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

in `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

but it does not work.
Does anybody know why such a strange behavior? In 2g/3g everything works, in wifi nothing works.

I tried to debug my app and I ran:

- `window.navigator.onLine` gives me `true`,
- `navigator.connection.type` gives me `wifi`.

Also when excecuting some AJAX calls I received: `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` from `jquery-2.1.4`.

Thanks

Comment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is coming from the WebView, even though you are online, it seems that you have connectivity problems with your WiFi connection.  And if your browser is working, have you tried without Crosswalk?  Those are some steps that you can try.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this problem? I am having the same issue. On android 6.x and older, the app works fine on WiFi however, on Android 7.x and newer it does not work on WiFi. We've tried numerous devices and it's all the same thing.

Comment: @recoilnetworks I have the same issue did you find a solution ?

Comment: Oh man, I do remember finding a resolution but I don't remember what it was. Sorry!